# How to see if a single array matches to another array inside an array of arrays with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
arrOne=[1,2,3]
```

I want to see if `arrOne` exists in an array of arrays such that if each element of `arrOne` is the same as the elements in an index of `arrTwo` or `arrThree` then it should return true!

```
arrTwo=[
  [1,2], [2], [1,3,5], [2,3,1]
]
arrThree=[
  [3,6,1], [2], [4,3,5], [2,3,9]
]
```

so our comparison should return true for (`arrOne` and `arrTwo`) and false for (`arrOne` and `arrThree`)

**Using es6 functions is a bonus**

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution.

Steps are:

1. Loop through the array containing nested arrays using [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method. It will return `true` as soon as its callback returns a truthy value, false otherwise.
2. Place candidate arrays length matching as the first condition (one of the arrays may have matching numbers with some missing or additional ones).
3. At this time it is the same if you loop one array or the other. Use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method. It will return `true` if the callback returns a truthy value for every tested item.
4. Finally, inside the last loop, check that each item is included in the other array by using the [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method which will return `true` if the array includes the passed element.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];

const array2 = [
  [1,2],
  [2],
  [1,3,5],
  [2,3,1]
];

const array3 = [
  [3,6,1],
  [2],
  [4,3,5],
  [2,3,9]
];

function compare(a1, b1) {
  return b1.some((b2) => {
    return b2.length === a1.length && a1.every((a2) => b2.includes(a2));
  });
}

console.log(compare(array1, array2));
console.log(compare(array1, array3));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer: what and why you’re doing helps future readers of this question.